Are there 105 verses in the Nestle Aland Gospels with 0 manuscript evidence?
I've heard advocates of the Byzantine text claim that Nestle Aland/UBS has over 200 verses in the Gospels alone that have zero manuscript evidence. Has anyone else heard this before? If so, where can one go to find a list?
Update:
The claim is 105 verses, not 200
One example verse that is often cited is Matthew 19:29
The Nestle Aland/UBS is translated into the ESV as such:

And everyone who has left houses or brothers or sisters or father
or mother or children or lands, for my name's sake, will receive a
hundredfold and will inherit eternal life.

However, only one manuscript (Vaticanus) reads the following:

houses or brothers or sisters or father or mother or children or lands

Almost all other manuscripts add "or wife."
However, while many manuscripts (and the NA/UBS) read

will receive a hundredfold (ἑκατονταπλασίονα) and will ...

Vaticanus reads

will receive manifold (πολλαπλασίονα) and will ...

Meaning that the textual critic is making the claim that not a single scribe managed to properly copy this verse down.
Second Update:
I found the source of the claims and it has all the verses listed. Thanks to anyone who may have been searching or trying to help.

As much I want to know the answer , I don't think this site will support a question like this, i.e. to substantiate a rumor.  But if you could produce a reference to those advocates claiming that, it can be a question to them to product that list.  You then can tag the question kjv-only.  This article should be very relevant to your query.

Hey Grateful Disciple. I will continue hunting down the claims. As a side note, the Byzantine text is quite different from the TR (KJV). I believe there are roughly 3400 different readings between the two, so I'm not sure KJV-only is a good tag.

The only substantial fact I can provide along these lines is the fact which Dean John Burgon publicised that Codex Sinaiticus and Codex Vaticanus differed from one another in 3,000 places in the gospels alone. See his book The Revision Revised.

Thanks for helping; I found the source article with all the verses listed. I posted an update to the q and an answer as well.
